# How to return two outputs - Drupal

Tags: php, drupal

I have a problem.
I created a function that returns a output. 
My problem is how to return two outputs on one page. Inside a function i have two db_query. The first one gives me teacher information

```
$temp = '';
    foreach($result as $item) {             
        $temp .= '<b>About teacher | </b>'. $item->title  .' '. $item->name .' '. $item->lname  .' , ' . $item->xyz .' <br />';
        $temp .= '<br/>';
        $temp .= '<b>E-mail | </b>' . $item->email  . '<br />';
        $temp .= '<br/>';
        if ($item->tel > "")
        {
            $temp .= '<b>Phone |  </b>'. $item->tel .''. $item->tele . '<br />';
            $temp .= '<br/>';
        }
        if ($item->cell > "")
        {
            $temp .= '<b>Mobile phone |  </b>'. $item->call .''. $item->cell . '<br />';
            $temp .= '<br/>';
        }               
    }
```

The other one returns a table and i use

```
    $output = theme('table', array('header'=> $header, 'rows' => $rows, 'empty' => t("None")));
```

Now when I use

```
return $temp;
return $output;
```

It returns only one "output". If $temp if first it returns about teacher if $output is first then it renders a table without the teacher information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Drupal, but is generic PHP. Return in PHP (and almost any language) means "return to the caller with this value". That means code after return is `never` ran.

```
return "foo";
print "I am never ran";
```

In your case, you want to glue the two strings together.

```
return $temp . $output;
```

The dot, *concatenates* two strings. and makes them one string.

Answer (score 0):

you can return it as array.

$t_array['v1'] = $temp;

$t_array['v2'] = $output;

return $t_array;